# how to reinitialize dbcontext?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I'm in a situation where my code needs to check some data in the `db` and then delete the `db` and then recreate and re-connect to it.

The thing is, my `DBContext` class has a `static` constructor and for some reason I can not re-initialize it.

This is what I do:

```
AppDBContext = new AppDBContext(); 
// Here CreateConnection is called - this is good.
```

Then I physically delete the database file

Then I just use the same code:

```
AppDBContext = new AppDBContext();
// for some reason the CreateConnection is not called 
// and when I try to initialize the database nothing happens...
```

Help !

Comment: Why do you need to do this? What do you want to happen in the initialization? The initialization only happens once in each domain app, generally when you create the first instance of your DbContext.

Comment: Because I have a db migration and this is only compulsory the second time around (this is indicated by a SetInitializer) in between the two initializations, the database is deleted and recreated.

Comment: What do you need to do on the first acces to the DB? What kind of app is it?

Comment: I need to get some data out of the db in order to perform a db synchronization before I delete it... it's a WPF application